# Where can I obtain the latest clang static analyzer?

Tags: clang-static-analyzer

On Ubuntu I can install scan-build from the clang-tools package. But for mac computer, there's no formula in homebrew and all I found online is this one: https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/downloads/

The last build is from 2016, where can I find the latest one?

Comment: The year 2021 version is "a python version" for python3 : `pip install scan-build` → Requires: Python 3.6 ... 3.9 https://pypi.org/project/scan-build/ .... ( source etc. https://github.com/rizsotto/scan-build )